# Identical ODE equations acting differently

Tags: r, math, ode

Hi guys I am having an issue with one of my equations in my ODE series. I have two equations that are exactly the same however they are coming out with very different answers. Is there a reason for my equations giving different answers?
The two equations are the ones governing e and r.

```
library(sigmoid)

parameters <- c(
                a = 0.032,
                b = (9 / 140),
                c = (5 / 1400),
                d = (95 / 700),
                k = 1 / 140,
                i = 0.25,
                # r = 0.2,
                n = 6000000,
                x = 0.5 ,
                y = 0.25,
                t = 1 / 180,        # important in looking at the shape
                u = 1 / 180,        # important in looking at the shape
                v = 1 / 180,        # important in looking at the shape
                p = 10,
                s = 100,
                g = 100

                # e = .4,
                #h = 1000
  ) 

  state <- c(
            S = 5989900,
            E = 0,
            I = 0,
            Q = 0,
            D = 100,
            B = 0,
            C = 100,
            Y = 100,
            H = 100,
            R = 10,
            J = 10,
            h = 100,
            e = 0.1,
            r = 0.1
   )

 # Function will transition between 0 and 1 when h and Q are approximately 
 equal
 smooth.transition <- function(h, Q, tune = 0.01){
 sigmoid((h/Q - 1)/tune)
 }
 Q <- 1
 h <- seq(0.001, 5, by = 0.001)

 plot(h/Q, j, type = "l")


 # set up the equations

 equation <- (function(t, state, parameters)
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    # rate of change

    dS <- (-(a * S * I) / n) - (((1 / r) * S * D) / n)
    dE <- (a * S * I) / n + (((1 / r) * S * D) / n) - i * E
    j <- smooth.transition(h, Q)
    dI <- i * (j) * E - (e) * I - c * I - d * I
    dQ <- (j) * (e) * I - b * Q - k * Q
    dD <- d * I - r * D
    dB <- b * Q + r * D
    dC <- c * I + k * Q

    dY <- p * (b * Q + r * D)
    dR <- j*(1 - x - y) * (p * (b * Q + r * D))  - j*t * (R)
    de <- j*t * (s / R)
    dJ <- (y) * (p * (b * Q + r * D))  - v * (J)
    dr <- v * (s / J)
    dH <- (x) * (p * (b * Q + r * D)) - u * (H)
    dh <- u * (H / g)


    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dS, dE, dI, dQ, dD, dB, dC, dY, dR, de, dJ, dr, dH, dh))
  }))
#

# solve the equations for certain starting parameters


library(deSolve)
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)

out <-
  ode(y = state,
    times = times,
    func = equation,
    parms = parameters,
    maxsteps = 1e5
  )
# , method = "vode"
head(out)
tail(out)

# graph the results

par(oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0))
plot(out, xlab = "Time", ylab = "People")
#plot(out[, "X"], out[, "Z"], pch = ".")
mtext(outer = TRUE, side = 3, "Ebola Model",cex = 1.5
)
```

What I get in the initial iterations for R, e, J and r are:

```
   R: 10, 10.05540, 10.11050
   e: 0.1, 59, 138

   J: 10, 39, 79
   r: 0.1, 0.105, 0.11
```

J and r are acting like I expect them to act while R and e are not. Can anyone see a problem in my coding. I think my maths is solid.

Comment: What do you mean "initial iterations"? Model solutions for early times? How do you expect your variables to behave? PS You can remove the definitions of Q and h and the neighbouring plot function. That was just to show you what the smoothing function looks like.

Comment: I expect at least unitll I change the parameters that R and J act the same and therefore as e and r are derivatives of J and R should also be the same

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The definitions of dR and dJ are not the same, so why would they behave the same?

Comment: Specifically, in the rightmost term of `dR` you have time (i.e., `t`), whereas the analogous term in `dJ` you don't.

Comment: Must have overlooked that bit then I changed t to v in the equation for e and R and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a parameter as `t` and the time in the solution as `t` also.

Answer (score 0):

The order you return your rates of change differs from the order you define your state variables initially.

cf

```
 state <- c(
            S = 5989900,
            E = 0,
            I = 0,
            Q = 0,
            D = 100,
            B = 0,
            C = 100,
            Y = 100,
            H = 100,
            R = 10,
            J = 10,
            h = 100,
            e = 0.1,
            r = 0.1
   )
```

with

```
list(c(dS, dE, dI, dQ, dD, dB, dC, dY, dR, de, dJ, dr, dH, dh))
```

The return list should read:

```
list(c(dS, dE, dI, dQ, dD, dB, dC, dY, dH, dR, dJ, dh, de, dr))
```

Comment: thanks that really helped! i was also wondering if i can use t as the period of time in the equations because it does not seem to be working

Comment: No problem! I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "period of time in the equations". Time step? Current time value? Can you post the code that isn't working and explain how you want it to work?

Comment: don't worry solved it, thanks so much for all your help, would have been lost otherwise

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!